# Training error rate in `caret`

Tags: r, r-caret

I don't know how to extract the training error (i.e., the error obtained on the training set) using the `caret` package in `R`. For example, I have the following model:

```
data(iris);
library(caret);
model<-train(Species~., data=iris, method='knn', trControl=trainControl(method='cv', number=10), tuneGrid=data.frame(k=20))
```

What I want to do is to see how well the model performed **on the training data**.

I know I can get the performance on the test set for each fold using `model$results`, but that's not what I want. I want to show how the training error is *way* over-optimistic, but I can't do that. The documentation here:

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/train

states that

> `results`: a data frame the training error rate and values of the tuning
>   parameters.

which is **not** true, because in my case, `model$results$Accuracy` is always **exactly** equal to the value of `mean(model$resample$Accuracy)`. This is the value of the *testing* error rate. I want the *training* eror rate. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: see this [post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114168/how-to-get-sub-training-and-sub-test-from-cross-validation-in-caret)

Comment: @phiver I don't really see how that post is helpful. It tells me nothing new and doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are asking for something like this:

```
model3<-train(Species~., data=iris, method='knn', trControl=trainControl(method='none'), tuneGrid=data.frame(k=20))
testPred <- predict(model3, iris)
postResample(testPred, iris$Species)

Accuracy    Kappa 
    0.98     0.97
```

Comment: I suppose, yes. But say I have a larger tuneGrid, and I want training accuracy for every `k` between `1` and `20`. Is this not possible simply with a clever call to `train`?